# Neither XPath nor Regular Expression Work on JMeter 3.0

Tags: regex, tomcat, xpath, jsf-2, jmeter

Undertaking load tests, I ran in a situation where I needed to use a dynamic variable (javax.faces.ViewState).

The solution is to use XPath or Regular Expressions extractors.

Both of them didn't work (...&javax.faces.ViewState=%24%7Bvar1%7D):

[image]

[image]

The value of the variables I used are

`<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(.+?)"autocomplete="off" />`

and

`//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value`

Source: http://se7so.blogspot.com/2012/12/apache-jmeter-along-with-jsf-pages.html

**UPDATE1:**

The generated parameter by JSF:

[image]

**UPDATE2**

Using google chrome's console:

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: In your first screen, you enter a regex in the XPath extractor form, right? Put the `//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value` in the XPath Extractor, it should work if there is such an `input` on the page.

Comment: Did you actually tried using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)? It would be useful seeing response data as well...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it didn't work and I updated the question. ${var1} is still misinterpreted.

Comment: When using Regular Expression Extractor try escaping all the quotes...

Comment: @IvanMarkovic, with //input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value? Escaping using backslash?

Comment: The problem is that the value of javax.faces.ViewState received on the server side is ${var1}. JMeter doesn't interpret what's between ${}.

Comment: That's because your _var1_ doesn't exist yet, 'cuz it wasn't extracted. Try this in your Regex Extractor : <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"javax\.faces\.ViewState\" id=\"javax\.faces\.ViewState\" value=\"(.+?)\"autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

1. For Regular Expressions you need to escape commas as they might be treated as [special characters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#DESCRIPTION), so use the following regular expression:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(.+?)" autocomplete="off" />
   ```

   Demo:

   [image: Regular Expression Extractor]
2. For the XPath Extractor if your response is not XML/XHTML-compliant you may need to check [Use Tidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) box to deal with "regular" HTML.

   [image: Xpath Demo]

By the way, you can verify your Regular, XPath, CSS and JSONPath expressions against live server response without having to re-run the test using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for details.

Comment: The problem is that I always get URL?javax.faces.ViewState=${var1}, whereas I mentioned a default value "NOTFOUND". ${var1} is considered a hardcoded value, rather than a variable.

Comment: JMeter Variables are **local** to the Thread Group, if you target to re-use this `ViewState` value across different Thread Groups you need to convert it to a JMeter Property via [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function. Refer to [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for instructions

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as regex in [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

> input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState"
>   id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="(.+?)"

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/dF4zV3/2) you can see it's working.